# magnific popup: zoom not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

When I look at the magnific popup site, the zoom works beautifully. When I install it on my own site I am getting no zoom in and a very choppy zoom out. I have to zoom module installed and I have copied the code exactly...

query...

```
$('.popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        closeBtnInside: false,
        fixedContentPos: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
        }
    });
```

css...

```
.mfp-with-zoom .mfp-container,
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-bg {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready .mfp-container {
    opacity: 1;
}
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing .mfp-container, 
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

I have no idea where to go from here

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same behaviour.  Any luck?